# top output Time+ information misleading

Tags: linux, top, suse

I am running SuSE 11.2. Shen I am running "top" command on one of my machine, it looks like this:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                               
 20456 root      20   0  8912 1184  820 R    126  0.0  5179143h top                                                                    
     1 root      20   0 10528  776  640 S      0  0.0 125107,48 init                                                                   
     2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0 275237,10 kthreadd                                                               
     3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0 300258:44 ksoftirqd/0                                                            
     4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:00.19 kworker/0:0                                                            
     6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                            
     7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:00.50 watchdog/0                                                             
     8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
```

My question is why the Time+ value is so big? The machine has only been running for several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is caused by a large value set in the /etc/adjtime